# js Diagonal movement at minute speeds

Tags: javascript

There are numerous questions on SO similiar to this but not exactly as far as I could tell.

Want to move an object along a path at a slow pace. Here's an example of what I've got.

```
var moverateX,moverateY;

function setup (){
var opp=targetY-startY;
var adj=targetX-startX;
var hyp=Math.sqrt ((opp*opp)+(adj*adj));
moverateY=10*(opp/hyp);
moverateX=10*(adj/hyp);}

function okgo (){
obj.style.left=currentX+moverateX+'px';
obj.style.top=currentY+moverateY+'px';
setTimeout (function (){okgo ();},50);}
```

It works but moves too quickly. If I change the number the ratio is multiplied by to a smaller one, the object misses the end target. eg:

```
var moverateY=2*(opp/hyp);
var moverateX=2*(adj/hyp);
//moves slower but misses the end mark by a fair margin
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve your code in two ways:

1. Using an absolute tracking instead of relative tracking
2. Using an absolute time control

### Absolute tracking

Javascript uses doubles for all computations so you do not have a real accuracy problem, but the formulas for absolute tracking are more accurate AND easier: given `(x0, y0)` as starting point and `(x1, y1)` as ending point you can compute any point inbetween the two with:

```
x = x0 + t*(x1 - x0);
y = y0 + t*(y1 - y0);
```

where `t` goes from 0.0 (start) to 1.0 (end).

### Absolute time control

This is where your code has a serious problem.
In Javascript (and in most other cases) when you set a timer you cannot be sure that the function will be called **exactly** what you want. The only thing you know for sure is the your function will not be called **more** than what you requested, but it's very common that some calls will be "late" in respect to the period you require.
To get a controlled movement over time you need to check the clock instead of just assuming the call time the expected one: to sum up...

```
function animate(div, x0, y0, x1, y1, speed) {
    var dx = x1 - x0;
    var dy = y1 - y0;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    var total_time = dist / speed;
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();
    var cback = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if (now >= start_time + total_time) {
            // Animation is complete
            div.style.left = x1 + "px";
            div.style.top = y1 + "px";
            //clearInterval(cback);
        } else {
            // We are still moving
            var t = (now - start_time) / total_time;
            div.style.left = (x0 + t*dx) + "px";
            div.style.top = (y0 + t*dy) + "px";
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Also the use of absolute timing simplifies for example "easing" (slow start and stop with acceleration and deceleration): just add after the computation of `t` the line

```
t = t*t*(3 - 2*t);
```

in this case the `speed` parameter means the **average** speed in px/ms.